# ASP.NET MVC - Display a message box when force a user logout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, cookie-authentication

I've a policy of my system, which is prevent multiple login. And I'm able to that by updating user's security stamp every time he/she logged in.

The following links are the method I used:
[Prevent Multiple Login in ASP.NET Identity](https://tech.trailmax.info/2015/09/prevent-multiple-logins-in-asp-net-identity/)
[CookieAuthenticationProvider and user session invalidation on change of SecurityStamp](https://tech.trailmax.info/2014/08/cookieauthenticationprovider-and-user-session-invalidation-on-change-of-securitystamp/)

The problem is I don't know how to display a message box to show to the user that is being force logged out.

Comment: Problem is that there is no effective/accurate way to know that another user is logged in somewhere else.

Comment: My way is update the security stamp